# Using JSON File in Android App Resources

Tags: android, json

Suppose I have a file with JSON contents in the raw resources folder in my app. How can I read this into the app, so that I can parse the JSON?

Comment: Note - now that this question is 10 years old, the top answers are no good.  Be sure to scroll down to the correct answers.  It's just one line of code.

Comment: how do I read the contents of a source XML file?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

See [openRawResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29). Something like this should work:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_file);
Writer writer = new StringWriter();
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
try {
    Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
    int n;
    while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
    }
} finally {
    is.close();
}

String jsonString = writer.toString();
```

Comment: What if i want to put the string in a String resource in android and use it dynamically using getResources().getString(R.String.name) ?

Comment: For me it doesn´t work because of the quotes, which are ignored when reading and which also seem to can not be escaped

Comment: Is there any way to make [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) bind the raw resource? Writing 10+ lines of code just to read a string seems like a little overkill.

Comment: How is the json stored inside the resources? Simply inside `\res\json_file.json` folder or inside `\res\raw\json_file.json`?

Comment: This answer lacks critical info.  Where can `getResources()` be called?  Where should the raw resource file go?   What convention should you follow to ensure the build tools create `R.raw.json_file`?

Answer (score 149):

Kotlin is now official language for Android, so I think this would be useful for someone

```
val text = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.your_text_file)
                                 .bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }
```

Comment: This is a potentially long running operation, so make sure this is called off the main thread!

Comment: @AndrewOrobator I've doubt that someone would put big json inside app resources, but yeah, nice point

Comment: This should be the verified answer

Answer (score 26):

I used @kabuko's answer to create an object that loads from a JSON file, using [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), from the Resources:

```
package com.jingit.mobile.testsupport;

import java.io.*;

import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;


/**
 * An object for reading from a JSON resource file and constructing an object from that resource file using Gson.
 */
public class JSONResourceReader {

    // === [ Private Data Members ] ============================================

    // Our JSON, in string form.
    private String jsonString;
    private static final String LOGTAG = JSONResourceReader.class.getSimpleName();

    // === [ Public API ] ======================================================

    /**
     * Read from a resources file and create a {@link JSONResourceReader} object that will allow the creation of other
     * objects from this resource.
     *
     * @param resources An application {@link Resources} object.
     * @param id The id for the resource to load, typically held in the raw/ folder.
     */
    public JSONResourceReader(Resources resources, int id) {
        InputStream resourceReader = resources.openRawResource(id);
        Writer writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceReader, "UTF-8"));
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                writer.write(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOGTAG, "Unhandled exception while using JSONResourceReader", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                resourceReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOGTAG, "Unhandled exception while using JSONResourceReader", e);
            }
        }

        jsonString = writer.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Build an object from the specified JSON resource using Gson.
     *
     * @param type The type of the object to build.
     *
     * @return An object of type T, with member fields populated using Gson.
     */
    public <T> T constructUsingGson(Class<T> type) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        return gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
    }
}
```

To use it, you'd do something like the following (the example is in an `InstrumentationTestCase`):

```
   @Override
    public void setUp() {
        // Load our JSON file.
        JSONResourceReader reader = new JSONResourceReader(getInstrumentation().getContext().getResources(), R.raw.jsonfile);
        MyJsonObject jsonObj = reader.constructUsingGson(MyJsonObject.class);
   }
```

Comment: Don't forget to add dependencies { compile com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2' } to your gradle file

Comment: last version of GSON is `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'`

Answer (score 19):

Like @mah states, the Android documentation (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) says that json files may be saved in the /raw directory under the /res (resources) directory in your project, for example:

```
MyProject/
  src/ 
    MyActivity.java
  res/
    drawable/ 
        graphic.png
    layout/ 
        main.xml
        info.xml
    mipmap/ 
        icon.png
    values/ 
        strings.xml
    raw/
        myjsonfile.json
```

Inside an `Activity`, the json file can be accessed through the `R` (Resources) class, and read to a String:

```
Context context = this;
Inputstream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.myjsonfile);
String jsonString = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

This uses the Java class `Scanner`, leading to less lines of code than some other methods of reading a simple text / json file. The delimiter pattern `\A` means 'the beginning of the input'. `.next()` reads the next token, which is the whole file in this case.

There are multiple ways to parse the resulting json string:

- Use the Java / Android built in [JSONObject](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) objects, like here: [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java). It may be convenient to get Strings, Integers etc. using the `optString(String name)`, `optInt(String name)` etc. methods, not the `getString(String name)`, `getInt(String name)` methods, because the `opt` methods return null instead of an exception in case of failing.
- Use a Java / Android json serializing / deserializing library like the ones mentiod here: https://medium.com/@IlyaEremin/android-json-parsers-comparison-2017-8b5221721e31

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, just two lines and done.Thanks

Comment: needs `import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStream;
import android.content.Context;`

Comment: Thanks, great stuff.  It's unfortunate that OS has some very old, totally wrong answers on very old questions like this one.

Answer (score 14):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html:

> **raw/**
>   Arbitrary files to save in their raw form. To open these resources with a raw InputStream, call Resources.openRawResource() with the resource ID, which is R.raw.filename.
>
> However, if you need access to original file names and file hierarchy, you might consider saving some resources in the assets/ directory (instead of res/raw/). Files in assets/ are not given a resource ID, so you can read them only using AssetManager.

Comment: If I want to embed a JSON file in my app, where should I put it? in assets folder or raw folder? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Found [this Kotlin snippet answer very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44460941/55488) ♥️

While the original question asked to get a JSON String, I figure some might find this useful. A step further with `Gson` leads to this little function with reified type:

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified T> readRawJson(@RawRes rawResId: Int): T {
    resources.openRawResource(rawResId).bufferedReader().use {
        return gson.fromJson<T>(it, object: TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
    }
}
```

Note you want to use `TypeToken` not just `T::class` so if you read a `List<YourType>` you won't lose the type by type erasure.

With the type inference you can then use like this:

```kotlin
fun pricingData(): List<PricingData> = readRawJson(R.raw.mock_pricing_data)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
InputStream is = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_regions);
                            int size = is.available();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                            is.read(buffer);
                            is.close();
                           String json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: use try catch block to avoid exceptions and crashes.

Answer (score 5):

**Using:**

```
String json_string = readRawResource(R.raw.json)
```

**Functions:**

```
public String readRawResource(@RawRes int res) {
    return readStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(res));
}

private String readStream(InputStream is) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```