# Android get data from json file (.txt)

Tags: android, json, string

I have Json file (test.txt) and I wanna get data from that file to Android App. My code is:

```
private static String url = "file:///AndroidJSONParsingActivity/res/raw/test.txt";
```

But it is not working. Error I get is:

```
error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Somebody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Put the `test.txt` file into assets folder

```
public class Utility {
   public static String readXMLinString(String fileName, Context c) {
      try {
          InputStream is = c.getAssets().open(fileName);
          int size = is.available();
          byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
          is.read(buffer);
          is.close();
          String text = new String(buffer);

          return text;
      } catch (IOException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can get `test.txt` using the following code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(Utility.readXMLinString("test.txt",getApplicationContext()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an answere [Using JSON File in Android App Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349759/using-json-file-in-android-app-resources)

You need to put the file intro raw folder and you can acces with this:

```
getResources().openRawResource(resourceName)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `getResources().openRawResource(RawResource_id)` for reading an text file from res/raw folder as:

```
 InputStream inputStream = Current_Activity.this.
                            getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);
 //put  your code for reading json from text file(inputStream) here
```

Answer (score 0):

use following code to open input stream for the file stored in the raw folder:

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code for that, it will solve your problem.

```
public void mReadJsonData() {
    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.textfilename)
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        String mResponse = new String(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```