# Reading a text file in android studio

Tags: android

I am currently developing android keyboard. I want to make word dictionary for the keyboard to suggest the words with respect to the user inputs. But dictionary is not an activity so, I cannot use `getAssets()` method to read text file if I put the text file in asset folder. Is there a way to read text document in Android Studio?

Comment: you want to read file in sub class of InputMethodService?

Comment: I mean are you extending any service, class where you want to use getAsseste()

Comment: I want to read a file within a class also it is not a sub class of any service or activity

Answer (score 0):

This is a list which should be stored in `SharedPreferences` or `Database` and should be loaded into memory(RAM) whenever the keyboard pops up. Getting from assets is an *IO operation* and its usages should be minimal.

If you want to read data from your .txt file, 
then you can prepare a `JSON` or `XML` and use `getAssets()` to read that JSON during initial startup of the "Application" and after that.

[UPDATE]
As requested in the answer

Here's how you can [read JSON data from the text file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13560360/8164116).

and [how to parse JSON](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm).

Comment: Can you further explain the second paragraph which is in your answer ?