# Insert personal folder into App

Tags: android, json, file

How can I insert a personal folder in which there are json file inside the app that I'm developing, and then get them to read the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create raw folder in res and put files in this then use it see these links.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource%28int%29

[Using JSON File in Android App Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349759/using-json-file-in-android-app-resources)