# Using local json file in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I will be using a local JSON file with some data. My question is where is the best/proper way to store the file and how should I access it and it's contents?

I have worked with json through http before but not a local one.

Comment: Your question isn't clear about whether the JSON file should be shipped as part of your app. If yes, ranjk89's answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, it will be part of the app.

Comment: Will the json file be always the same or do you plan to change it with your up while running? If it is going to be static use assets folder if not use the local storage of the device.

Comment: It will always be the same

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are so many ways,

- You can store your JSON file in assets folder and read them like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945484/713778
- You can store it in res/raw folder and read the same as show here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349913/713778

For basic JSON parsing, Android's in-built JSONObject should work - https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

For more advanced JSON parsing (json-java mapping), you can look at GSON library - https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Is any of ways above better than the other? Or does both work as good?