# load JSON with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, json

Is it possible to load JSON file once, and in further call will use loaded JSON (for ex. from cache)?

Comment: Please post some relevant code for better understanding the issue

Comment: Its very hard to answer this question since many would find it really hard to understand, i know Im having a hard time.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I simplified the question

Comment: Why not just store the JSON in a variable?

Comment: @JacquesMarais the storage is 5MB and not enough for using

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use the `localStorage` of JavaScript. 
Let's assume you have an object named `object`.

You can store it this way:

```
// parse Object to JSON, then store it.
let jsonObject = JSON.stringify(object);
localStorage.setItem('myObject', jsonObject);
```

And if you want to use it again, do it this way:

```
// load it from storage and parse the JSON to Object.
let jsonObject = localStorage.getItem('myObject');
let object = null;

if(jsonObject){
    object  = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
}
```

Then change it according to your needs and store it again.

You can delete it by

```
localStorage.removeItem('myObject');
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so *many ways,*

You can store your JSON file in assets folder and read them like this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945484/713778

You can store it in res/raw folder and read the same as show here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6349913/713778

For basic JSON parsing, Android's in-built JSONObject should work - https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

For more advanced JSON parsing (json-java mapping), you can look at GSON library - https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/