# Insert JSON Array on String Array on android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have JSON array like below format

```
{
"get": [],
"post": {
    "_event": "get_buyers_guide_detail",
    "_deviceID": "490154203237518",
    "type": "cars",
    "model_id": "1007"
},
"cars": [
    {
        "ID": 6119,
        "post_title": "COROLLA",
        "interior_images": [
            "http://.....e8664969d20654bf2a58f1b26de70d2.jpg",
            "http://........02/3bdfae250e3ce14514fe8f2f9dc3e58f.jpg",
            "http://........1d14a554a2ed78d1659463ec.jpg"
        ],

    }
]
}
```

I have create JSONArray for this:

```
JSONArray Array = entries.getJSONArray("cars");
for (int i = 0; i < Array.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject detailObject = Array.getJSONObject(i);
   String ID = detailObject.getString("ID");
   String title = detailObject.getString("post_title");
   JSONArray galleryArray = detailObject.getJSONArray("interior_images");
   for(int j=0; j<galleryArray.length(); j++){
      // What to do here ????   
   }
}
```

now i am confused with this format of JSON data. There is no JSONObject to get the values. How to insert these string on `Array` please help me find out the solution

Comment: Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: @Prince im only showing here my important part

Comment: show your complete JSON

Comment: @user3751280 keys are very important in JSON. You are missing them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON Array of strings (no objects), extracting data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147851/json-array-of-strings-no-objects-extracting-data)

Comment: always verify that your JSON is valid or not you can use http://pro.jsonlint.com/

Comment: Your json is not valid.

Comment: Its valid json, The string array is directly converted into JsonArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
galleryArray.getString(j);
```

this should get the string at position **`j`**.

Answer (score 1):

`galleryArray.getString(index);`

This function will return `String` object of corresponding index

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

 JSONArray galleryArray = detailObject.getJSONArray("interior_images");
for(int j=0; j<galleryArray.length(); j++){
  try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = galleryArray.getJSONObject(j);
        stringArray.add(jsonObject.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
try{
    String jsonRespone="{\"get\":[],\"post\":{\"_event\":\"get_buyers_guide_detail\",\"_deviceID\":\"490154203237518\",\"type\":\"cars\",\"model_id\":\"1007\"},\"cars\":[{\"ID\":6119,\"post_title\":\"COROLLA\",\"interior_images\":[\"http://.....e8664969d20654bf2a58f1b26de70d2.jpg\",\"http://........02/3bdfae250e3ce14514fe8f2f9dc3e58f.jpg\",\"http://........1d14a554a2ed78d1659463ec.jpg\"],}]}";
    JSONObject responeJson = new JSONObject(jsonRespone);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    JSONArray carsJsonArray = responeJson.getJSONArray("cars");
    for (int i=0;i<carsJsonArray.length();i++){
        HashMap<String,Object> row = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        row.put("ID",carsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ID"));
        row.put("TITLE",carsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_title"));
        JSONArray galleryArray = carsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("interior_images");
        ArrayList<String> interiorImages = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int j=0; j<galleryArray.length(); j++){
           interiorImages.add(galleryArray.getString(j));
        }
        row.put("INTERIORIMAGES",carsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("interiorImages"));
           data.add(row);
        }
        for (HashMap<String,Object> row :data){
            System.out.print("ID : "+row.get("ID"));
            System.out.print("TITLE : "+row.get("TITLE"));
            ArrayList<String> interiorImages =  (ArrayList<String>) row.get("INTERIORIMAGES");
            for (int j=0;j<interiorImages.size();j++){
                System.out.print("INTERIORIMAGES  +"+j+" : "+interiorImages.get(j));
            }
         }
  }catch (Throwable e){
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use List of Map

Example:

```
 List<Map> list = new ArrayList<Map>();
 Map map = new HashMap();
 map.put("userIcon", R.drawable.scott);
 map.put("username", "Shen");
 map.put("usertext", "This is a simple sample for SimpleAdapter");
 list.add(map);


 map = new HashMap();
 map.put("userIcon", R.drawable.ricardo);
 map.put("username", "Ricardo");
 map.put("usertext", "This is a simple sample for SimpleAdapter");
 list.add(map);
```

add this in loop