# JSONException when parse a valid Json

Tags: java, android, json

I try to parse this valid JSON

I use `new JSONObject(resultString);`  but i have JSONException

How can i parse his Json

Help me please!

Thanks

```
[{
    "id": "8637F7F78C8C1",
    "from_account_id": "1025630",
    "to_account_id": "1025635",
    "transaction_type_id": "15",
    "transaction_mode_id": "2",
    "transaction_status_id": "1",
    "amount": "1000.00",
    "real_amount": "1000.00",
    "promote_amount": "0.00",
    "from_fix_fee_amount": "0.00",
    "from_percent_fee_amount": "50.00",
    "to_fix_fee_amount": "0.00",
    "to_percent_fee_amount": "0.00",
    "description": "demo",
    "created_on": "2012-07-16 10:04:29",
    "activated_on": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "executed_on": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "verify_transaction_by": "o",
    "from_account_name": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "from_account_email": "xxxxxxx@gmail.com",
    "from_account_phone_no": "xxcxxxxxx",
    "to_account_name": "yyyyyyy",
    "to_account_email": "yyyyy@gmail.com",
    "to_account_phone_no": "yyyyyyyy"
},
{
    "id": "A26BF7F75534B",
    "from_account_id": "1014635",
    "to_account_id": "1054630",
    "transaction_type_id": "5",
    "transaction_mode_id": "2",
    "transaction_status_id": "4",
    "amount": "1000.00",
    "real_amount": "1000.00",
    "promote_amount": "0.00",
    "from_fix_fee_amount": "0.00",
    "from_percent_fee_amount": "0.00",
    "to_fix_fee_amount": "0.00",
    "to_percent_fee_amount": "0.00",
    "description": "",
    "created_on": "2012-07-15 00:52:40",
    "activated_on": "2012-07-15 00:53:19",
    "executed_on": "2012-07-15 00:54:57",
    "verify_transaction_by": "o",
    "from_account_name": "yyyyyy",
    "from_account_email": "yyyyyy@gmail.com",
    "from_account_phone_no": "yyyyyyy",
    "to_account_name": "wwwwwww",
    "to_account_email": "yywywyyy@gmail.com",
    "to_account_phone_no": "yyyyyyyyy"
}]
```

Comment: 07-17 19:48:53.650: W/System.err(15185): org.json.JSONException: Value "xxxxxx"
07-17 19:48:53.660: W/System.err(15185):  at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)

Comment: Share the Stacktrace. That may give us more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a `JSONArray` not a `JSONObject` ..
[JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java)

```
JSONArray values = new JSONArray(resultString);
for(int i = 0 ; i < values.length(); i++){
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) values.get(i); 
    String id = object.getString("id");
    //the same for the rest
}
```

Comment: how can i parse this JsonArray

Answer (score 1):

That's not a JSON object - it's a JSON array containing two objects.

Use `new JSONArray(resultString);` first then get the objects from that.

Comment: when i use : new JSONArray(resultString);  i have the JSONException

Answer (score 1):

Hi [] denotes array in JSON, so after parsing try to put it in JSONArray... `new JSONArray(resultString).getJSONObject(int index);`

in this manner you can get JSON Object..

Answer (score 1):

For parsing JSON I used [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse("json text");
```

> JsonArray array = jobject.getAsJsonArray("myarray");
>   for
>   (JsonElement item : array) {...}