# org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray in android

Tags: android, json, url

When I try in my localhost it work find. this is the JSON that provide by my localhost.

Y it error in this url http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/

```
         [{
     "id": "1",
     "first_name": "man",
     "last_name": "woman",
     "username": "man",
     "password": "4f70432e6369
70de9929bcc6f1b72412",
     "email": "man@gmail.com",
     "url": "http:\/\/localhost\/adchara1\/"
 }, {
     "id": "6",
     "first_name": "first",
     "last_name": "Last 
Name",
     "username": "user",
     "password": "1a1dc91c907325c69271ddf0c944bc72",
     "email": "0",
     "url": "ht
tp:\/\/api.androidhive.info\/contacts\/"
 }, {
     "id": "7",
     "first_name": "1",
     "last_name": "2",
     "username": "us45",
     "password": "33d8f54e33896a5722
7b18642979e558",
     "email": "first@gmail.com",
     "url": "http:\/\/ugirusgiarto.wordpress.com\/2011\
/10\/27\/json-php-mysql-with-asynctask-progressdialog\/"
 }, {
     "id": "9",
     "first_name": "First Name",
     "last_name": "Last 
Name",
     "username": "Username",
     "password": "dc647eb65e6711e155375218212b3964",
     "email": "woman@gm
ail.com",
     "url": "http:\/\/mobile.cs.fsu.edu\/parse-json-objects-in-asynctask\/"
 }]
```

x

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text_1, text_2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new task().execute();
    }

    class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                MainActivity.this);
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog.setMessage("Download data...");
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                    task.this.cancel(true);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
//          String url_select = "http://192.168.10.111/adchara1/";
             String url_select = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                // read content
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result = sb.toString();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

            // ambil data dari Json database
            try {
                JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
                    text_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                    Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    // get an output on the screen
                    String id = Jasonobject.getString("id");
                    String name = Jasonobject.getString("name");
                    String email = Jasonobject.getString("email");
                    String address = Jasonobject.getString("address");
                    String gender = Jasonobject.getString("gender");
                    text_1.append("\n" + id + "\t\t" + name + "\t\t\t"
                            + email + "\t\t\t\t" + address + "\t\t\t\t" + gender
                            + "\t\t\t\t" + "\n");

                }
                this.progressDialog.dismiss();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

ERROR

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {
    "contacts": [{
        "id": "c200",
        "gender": "male",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
        "name": "Ravi Tamada"
    }, {
        "id": "c201",
        "gender": "male",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "johnny_depp@gmail.com",
        "name": "Johnny Depp"
    }, {
        "id": "c202",
        "gender": "male",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "leonardo_dicaprio@gmail.com",
        "name": "Leonardo Dicaprio"
    }, {
        "id": "c203",
        "gender": "male",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "john_wayne@gmail.com",
        "name": "John Wayne"
    }, {
        "id": "c204",
        "gender": "female",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "angelina_jolie@gmail.com",
        "name": "Angelina Jolie"
    }, {
        "id": "c205",
        "gender": "female",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "dido@gmail.com",
        "name": "Dido"
    }, {
        "id": "c206",
        "gender": "female",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "adele@gmail.com",
        "name": "Adele"
    }, {
        "id": "c207",
        "gender": "male",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "hugh_jackman@gmail.com",
        "name": "Hugh Jackman"
    }, {
        "id": "c208",
        "gender": "male",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "will_smith@gmail.com",
        "name": "Will Smith"
    }, {
        "id": "c209",
        "gender": "male",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "clint_eastwood@gmail.com",
        "name": "Clint Eastwood"
    }, {
        "id": "c2010",
        "gender": "male",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "barack_obama@gmail.com",
        "name": "Barack Obama"
    }, {
        "id": "c2011",
        "gender": "female",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "kate_winslet@gmail.com",
        "name": "Kate Winslet"
    }, {
        "id": "c2012",
        "gender": "male",
        "phone": {
            "office": "00 000000",
            "home": "00 000000",
            "mobile": "+91 0000000000"
        },
        "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
        "email": "eminem@gmail.com",
        "name": "Eminem"
    }]
}
of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: I'd suggest trying with something you know is a valid JSONArray to make sure your code works and then checking to see if this is in fact a valid JSONArray. You can use tools like Google Chrome's "JSON Formatter" extension to help you read JSON in an indented, formatted way

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try this:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray Jarray  = object.getJSONArray("contacts");

for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) 
{
   JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The url (http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/) returns a JSON object and not a JSON array...

**Here:**

```
JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
```

You are assuming the result is a json array. If you do it like the following it will work:

```
JSONObject Jasonobject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray Jarray = Jasonobject.getJSONArray("contacts");

for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) { ...}
```

Answer (score 3):

try using this

```
JSONObject Jarray = new JSONObject(result);
```

instead of

```
JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
```

and next

```
JSONArray Jarray = Jasonobject.getJSONArray("contacts");
```

and the for loop continues

**Download image from URL**

Pass the URL to this particular method and you can download the image to the gridview

```
private void downloadImage(String urlStr) {
    final String url = urlStr;
            InputStream in = null;
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = 1;
            try {
                in = openHttpConnection(url);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
                msg.setData(b);
                in.close();

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           
}

private InputStream openHttpConnection(String urlStr) {
    InputStream in = null;
    int resCode = -1;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

        if (!(urlConn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) {
            throw new IOException ("URL is not an Http URL");
        }

        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)urlConn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();

        resCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();                
        if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                
        }        
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return in;
}
```

Comment: this is not the main problem. the main problem, I want to use the path  image in json. I want my imageview view image using the image path from json. check the link abov

Comment: This is what I want. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739824/image-viewer-get-image-from-url-that-provide-image-path-as-json-string

Answer (score 1):

try the following to convert :

```
         JSONObject js= new JSONObject(yourjsonobjectvalue);
         JSONArray jA = js.getJSONArray("String value");
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that your JSON is a `JSON Object` and not an `JSON Array`:

change:

```
JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result)
```

to

```
JSONObject someObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray Jarray = Jarray.getJSONArray("contacts");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(uri.toString());

        try {
            //Obter objeto JSON
            clientesJSONArray = json.optJSONArray(Clientes.TABELA);

            //Se for 1 objeto não virá em JSONArray - Os objetos em JSON são separados
            //por colchetes [] - No caso de um objeto, não será array e sim um simples
            //objeto em JSON
            if(clientesJSONArray==null){
                // means item is JSONObject instead of JSONArray
                //json = obj.optJSONObject("offerRideResult");
                JSONObject obj = json.getJSONObject(Clientes.TABELA);

                Clientes oCliente = new Clientes();
                oCliente.setCliente(obj.getString(Clientes.CLIENTE));
                oCliente.setCod_cliente(obj.getInt(Clientes.COD_CLIENTE));
                oCliente.setE_mail(obj.getString(Clientes.E_MAIL));
                oCliente.setUsuario(obj.getString(Clientes.USUARIO));
                oCliente.setUsuario(obj.getString(Clientes.SENHA));


                clientesList.add(oCliente);

            }else{
                // Mais de um objeto JSON separado por colchetes [] - JSONArray ao invés JSONObject
                for (int i = 0; i < clientesJSONArray.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject obj = clientesJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Clientes oCliente = new Clientes();
                    oCliente.setCliente(obj.getString(Clientes.CLIENTE));
                    oCliente.setCod_cliente(obj.getInt(Clientes.COD_CLIENTE));
                    oCliente.setE_mail(obj.getString(Clientes.E_MAIL));
                    oCliente.setUsuario(obj.getString(Clientes.USUARIO));
                    oCliente.setUsuario(obj.getString(Clientes.SENHA));


                    clientesList.add(oCliente);


                }
            }
```