# JSONObject cannot be converted to JSON Array error

Tags: php, json

I am getting the error org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSON Array. I have tried to implement some solutions here, but have not been successful. The tutorial I am using implements a response and when I edit, there are breakS. I want to be sure I do it correctly. I appreciate any help given.

From my activity.java

```
private void getJSON() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    String url = URL_Alerts;

    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        // looping through json and adding to movies list
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject alertObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                int id = alertObj.getInt("id");
                                String image = alertObj.isNull("image") ? null:alertObj
                                        .getString("image");
                                String name = alertObj.getString("name");
                                String date = alertObj.getString("date");
                                String order = alertObj.getString("order");
                                String pair = alertObj.getString("pair");
                                String rate = alertObj.getString("rate");
                                String quick_target = alertObj.getString("quick_target");
                                String long_target = alertObj.getString("long_target");
                                String stop_loss = alertObj.getString("stop_loss");
                                String break_even = alertObj.getString("break_even");
                                String status = alertObj.getString("status");
                                String profileImageView = alertObj.getString("profilePic");
                                String feedImageView = alertObj.getString("feedImageView");

                                Alert a = new Alert(id, name, date, order, pair, rate,
                                        quick_target, long_target,stop_loss, break_even,
                                        status, profileImageView, feedImageView, image);

                                alertList.add(0, a);

                                // updating offset value to highest value
                                if (id >= offSet)
                                    offSet = id;

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // stopping swipe refresh
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Here is the php file

```
    <?php 
    //Importing Database Script 
    require_once('dbConnectalerts.php');

    //Creating sql query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM alerts";

    //getting result 
    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    //creating a blank array 
    $result = array();

    //looping through all the records fetched
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

    //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
    array_push($result,array(
    "id"=>$row['id'],
    "order"=>$row['order'],
    "pair"=>$row['pair'],
    "rate"=>$row['rate'],
    "quick_target"=>$row['quick_target'],
    "long_target"=>$row['long_target'],
    "stop_loss"=>$row['stop_loss'],
    "break_even"=>$row['break_even'],
    "name"=>$row['name'],
    "status"=>$row['status']
    ));
     }

    //Displaying the array in json format 

    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);
```

This is the output when pulled from url.

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","order":"BUY","pair":"EURGBP","rate":"1.6025","quick_target":"1.6035","long_target":"1.6055","stop_loss":"1.5975","break_even":"1.6030","name":"EURGBP","status":"BETA ENTRY"},{"id":"2","order":"Sell","pair":"GBPAUD","rate":"1.5050","quick_target":"1.5040","long_target":"1.5010","stop_loss":"1.5099","break_even":"1.5040","name":"GBPAUD","status":"Beta testing"}]}
```

Here is what I am getting when I edit with the solution provided.

```
    private void getJSON() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    String url = URL_Alerts;

    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result); //cannot resolve symbol result
    JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("result");  //unhandled exception

    for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) { //variable i is already handled in the scope
        JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i); //unhandled exception
                        for (int i = 0; i < Jarry.length(); i++) { //cannot resolve symbol Jarry
                            try {
                                JSONObject alertObj = Jarry.getJSONObject(i);

                                int id = alertObj.getInt("id");
                                String image = alertObj.isNull("image") ? null:alertObj
                                        .getString("image");
                                String name = alertObj.getString("name");
                                String date = alertObj.getString("date");
                                String order = alertObj.getString("order");
                                String pair = alertObj.getString("pair");
                                String rate = alertObj.getString("rate");
                                String quick_target = alertObj.getString("quick_target");
                                String long_target = alertObj.getString("long_target");
                                String stop_loss = alertObj.getString("stop_loss");
                                String break_even = alertObj.getString("break_even");
                                String status = alertObj.getString("status");
                                String profileImageView = alertObj.getString("profilePic");
                                String feedImageView = alertObj.getString("feedImageView");

                                Alert a = new Alert(id, name, date, order, pair, rate,
                                        quick_target, long_target,stop_loss, break_even,
                                        status, profileImageView, feedImageView, image);

                                alertList.add(0, a);

                                // updating offset value to highest value
                                if (id >= offSet)
                                    offSet = id;

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // stopping swipe refresh
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

}

Here is the full java class.

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.brasiltradefx.btfxalertsadmin.app.MyApplication;
import com.brasiltradefx.btfxalertsadmin.helper.Alert;
import com.brasiltradefx.btfxalertsadmin.helper.SwipeListAdapter;



/**
 * Created by Deryk on 12/2/2015.
 */
public class AlertMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener{
    private static final String TAG = AlertMainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private String URL_Alerts = "http://www.contrariantradefx.info/android/btfxalerts/alerts_all_data.php";

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private SwipeListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Alert> alertList;
    private int offSet = 0;
    private String JSON_STRING;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alert_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        alertList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new SwipeListAdapter(this, alertList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
                getJSON();
            }
        }
    );
}

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        getJSON();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getJSON();
}

    private void getJSON() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        String url = URL_Alerts;

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        if (response.length() > 0) {
                            // looping through json and adding to movies list
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject alertObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int id = alertObj.getInt("id");
                                    String image = alertObj.isNull("image") ? null:alertObj
                                            .getString("image");
                                    String name = alertObj.getString("name");
                                    String date = alertObj.getString("date");
                                    String order = alertObj.getString("order");
                                    String pair = alertObj.getString("pair");
                                    String rate = alertObj.getString("rate");
                                    String quick_target = alertObj.getString("quick_target");
                                    String long_target = alertObj.getString("long_target");
                                    String stop_loss = alertObj.getString("stop_loss");
                                    String break_even = alertObj.getString("break_even");
                                    String status = alertObj.getString("status");
                                    String profileImageView = alertObj.getString("profilePic");
                                    String feedImageView = alertObj.getString("feedImageView");

                                    Alert a = new Alert(id, name, date, order, pair, rate,
                                            quick_target, long_target,stop_loss, break_even,
                                            status, profileImageView, feedImageView, image);

                                    alertList.add(0, a);

                                    // updating offset value to highest value
                                    if (id >= offSet)
                                        offSet = id;

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        // stopping swipe refresh
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // stopping swipe refresh
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }

}
```

hooray! Issue solved. I made a few tweaks and now the error is gone. Thank you for your help Prerak Sola!

Final edits

```
enter code h  private void getJSON() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    String url = URL_Alerts;

    JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    //Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                    try {
                        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                        // looping through json and adding to movies list
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject alertObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                int id = alertObj.getInt("id");
                                String image = alertObj.isNull("image") ? null : alertObj
                                        .getString("image");
                                String name = alertObj.getString("name");
                                String date = alertObj.getString("date");
                                String order = alertObj.getString("order");
                                String pair = alertObj.getString("pair");
                                String rate = alertObj.getString("rate");
                                String quick_target = alertObj.getString("quick_target");
                                String long_target = alertObj.getString("long_target");
                                String stop_loss = alertObj.getString("stop_loss");
                                String break_even = alertObj.getString("break_even");
                                String status = alertObj.getString("status");
                                String profileImageView = alertObj.getString("profilePic");
                                String feedImageView = alertObj.getString("feedImageView");

                                Alert a = new Alert(id, name, date, order, pair, rate,
                                        quick_target, long_target, stop_loss, break_even,
                                        status, profileImageView, feedImageView, image);

                                alertList.add(0, a);

                                // updating offset value to highest value
                                if (id >= offSet)
                                    offSet = id;

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Comment: The response is a `JSONObjct` and not a `JSONArray`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722468/org-json-jsonobject-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray-in-android)

Comment: I understand that it is a JSONObject and not an array. The issue I am having is that when I change to JsonArray to JSONObject, the code is breaking further down. I tried to delete the response portion, but I get an error telling me I cannot use "i" in the line JSONObject alertObj = response.getJSONObject(i).

Comment: @RajeshJadav - Thank you. I was actually trying to implement that solution, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void getJSON() {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

    String url = URL_Alerts;

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
       (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() 
    {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("result");    

                    if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
                        // looping through json and adding to movies list
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject alertObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                int id = alertObj.getInt("id");
                                String image = alertObj.isNull("image") ? null:alertObj
                                        .getString("image");
                                String name = alertObj.getString("name");
                                String date = alertObj.getString("date");
                                String order = alertObj.getString("order");
                                String pair = alertObj.getString("pair");
                                String rate = alertObj.getString("rate");
                                String quick_target = alertObj.getString("quick_target");
                                String long_target = alertObj.getString("long_target");
                                String stop_loss = alertObj.getString("stop_loss");
                                String break_even = alertObj.getString("break_even");
                                String status = alertObj.getString("status");
                                String profileImageView = alertObj.getString("profilePic");
                                String feedImageView = alertObj.getString("feedImageView");

                                Alert a = new Alert(id, name, date, order, pair, rate,
                                        quick_target, long_target,stop_loss, break_even,
                                        status, profileImageView, feedImageView, image);

                                alertList.add(0, a);

                                // updating offset value to highest value
                                if (id >= offSet)
                                    offSet = id;

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    // stopping swipe refresh
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // stopping swipe refresh
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
}
```

Comment: - I tried that, but I get more errors. The new Response.Listener<JSONArray> line says the anonymous class derived from listener has to be declared abstract...  get an unhandled exception for response.getJSONArray("result")  and a whole bunch of errors further down where the ErrorListener is.

Comment: I will try to do that. For some reason the editor keeps breaking it into 4 pieces...

Comment: Ok. I was able to include the full class. Thanks for taking a look. I appreciate that!

Comment: I had a few small errors still, but I made a few little changes. I'm going to run it thru the emulator now and see what we get.

Comment: i made a few edits and now its working. I certainly appreciate your assistance, sir!