# Retrieving JSON in android with single line object structure

Tags: java, android, json

I'm quite new to *JSON* and it's operation I was trying to retrieve *JSON* from server

```
 datafromServer = bufferedReader.readLine();
                inputStream.close();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(datafromServer );
```

and came accross to this exception :

> org.json.JSONException: Value
>   {"last_name":"Hicks","id":18,"email":"dwaynehicks@usssulaco.com","first_name":"Dwayne"}
>   of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

So  I found [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722468/org-json-jsonobject-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray-in-android) answer  :

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("contacts");

for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
```

Now, the problem is, in the answer, OP had object formation of :

```
 "contacts": [{
        .....
        .....

         ]
```

in this JSON. While I get formation of (*no key* mapped to this line) :

```
{"last_name":"Hicks","id":18,"email":"dwaynehicks@usssulaco.com","first_name":"Dwayne"}
```

So how  I modified this line `*JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("contacts");*`?
I don't have such key.

Thanks

Comment: Try `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(dataFromServer)` instead of `JSONArray`

Comment: So is '{"last_name":"Hicks","id":18,"email":"dwaynehicks@usssulaco.com","first_name":"Dwayne"}' all the JSON you are trying to read, or is this just part of it?

Comment: Thank you guys... you guys got my question correctly as I'm not asking about exception rather *structure* access. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a JSONArray you can just get the data from the JSONObject like this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
String lastName = jsonObject.getString("last_name");
int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
String firstName = jsonObject.getString("first_name");
```

Comment: So you have just fixed my understanding about the structure thank you

Answer (score 2):

`{"last_name":"Hicks","id":18,"email":"dwaynehicks@usssulaco.com","first_name":"‌​Dwayne"}`

^ Is an instance of a single JSON object.

```
{"contacts": [{...}, {...}]}
```

^ Is an instance of a single JSON Array. A JSON array can have 0 to many JSON Object in it.

The first error is caused by trying to make a JSONArray with a String that represents a JsonObject.

The "answer" that you found is an example of someone reading a JsonObject, getting a JsonArray (contacts) from that object, and then looping through all JsonObjects in that JsonArray. This doesn't apply to you because you simply have one flat JsonObject.

Read up on the API to find which methods are appropriate for getting each type. In this case, since you have a String object that is exactly one JsonObject you can use JsonObjects constructor that takes a String like @SripadRaj said in the comments.

Comment: So you have just fixed my understanding about the structure thank you

Comment: If you ever have problems understanding a JSON, copy and paste it into an online JSON editor. Many of them have tools that will turn the text version of it into a visual representation. http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: Thank you, though, how can possibly a json editor makes me understand the json itself :D

Comment: @Hey-men-whatsup Take a JSON object that is confusing. Paste it in the left and then hit the right array in the center. On the right you will see a (maybe for some) easier to understand display of the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Json code needs to get into the `try catch`

```
   try{
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray Jarray = object.getJSONArray("contacts");

       for (int i = 0; i < Jarray.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);
            String lastName = jsonObject.getString("last_name");
            int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
            String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
            String firstName = jsonObject.getString("first_name");
       }
    }catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Hmm... you misunderstood my question but plus one anyway :D