# Android: org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve certain JSON data from a webserver, which I want to use to display a certain value in an android app. The request is successful (as in, the data is retrieved from the server), but when I want to actually use the JSON, I get the error `org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray`. The JSON retrieved has the following structure:

```
{
  "590b14eb66b8f3786317e571": {
    "updatedAt": "2017-05-04T11:47:55.000Z",
    "created_at": "2017-05-04T11:47:55.000Z",
    "UId": "590b10981da091b2618a4914",
    "value": 37,
    "_id": "590b14eb66b8f3786317e571",
    "__v": 0
  }
}
```

In this example, `590b14eb66b8f3786317e571` is the ID of the MongoDB document, which can change for every request. So I can't use that to get the required element from the JSON array. The key I'm interested in is "value".

Code to retrieve data:

```
private JSONArray getSingleTemperature(URL url) throws IOException, JSONException {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        String forecastJsonString = null;

        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("charset", "UTF-8");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if(inputStream == null) {
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if(buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            forecastJsonString = buffer.toString();
            Log.i("JSON", forecastJsonString);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if(reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceHolderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }

        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(forecastJsonString);
        return ja;
    }
```

To then get the actual keys/values required, I'm trying to use this code:

```
@Override
public void processFinish(JSONArray json) {
    try {
        if(json != null) {
            JSONObject jo = json.getJSONObject(0);
            String temp = jo.getString("value");
            temperature = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            temperatureView.setText(temp + "°C");
            checkTemperature();
        } else {
            buildAlertDialog(getResources().getString(R.string.server_error_title), getResources().getString(R.string.server_error_message));
        }
    } catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've already looked through other questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722468/org-json-jsonobject-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray-in-android) one), but [most solutions seem to be build on knowing the name of the root element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12722563/2466375) (which in this example is `590b14eb66b8f3786317e571`), however, in my case this name changes every time so I can't reliably use this name. Is there a way to remove the `{"590b14eb66b8f3786317e571": }` part, and only use the actual included data:

```
{
    "updatedAt": "2017-05-04T11:47:55.000Z",
    "created_at": "2017-05-04T11:47:55.000Z",
    "UId": "590b10981da091b2618a4914",
    "value": 37,
    "_id": "590b14eb66b8f3786317e571",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Or is there a way to otherwise parse the retrieved `string` so I can get the `value` key from the JSON object?

Edit: I've tried two different solutions using iteration, however I still get the same error. The first solution (based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject) question):

```
@Override
public void processFinish(JSONArray json) {
    try {
        if(json != null) {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json.toString());
            Iterator<?> keys = jo.keys();
            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String)keys.next();
                if(jo.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                    String temp = jo.getString("value");
                    temperature = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                    temperatureView.setText(temp + "°C");
                    checkTemperature();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second solution, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java) question:

```
@Override
public void processFinish(JSONArray json) {
    try {
        if(json != null) {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(json.toString());
            String temp;
            for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject row = json.getJSONObject(i);
                temp = row.getString("value");
                temperature = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                temperatureView.setText(temp + "°C");
                checkTemperature();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Neither of these solutions fix the problem, so I assume the problems lies in the part before the `processFinish` method is called.

Comment: I know, I've tried using those, but I can't successfully get the `value` key from the `JSONObject`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over a JSONObject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9151619/how-to-iterate-over-a-jsonobject)

Comment: huh? what about `var value = jsonObject.get(key)`

Comment: Please see my edit. I've tried using solutions to two different questions, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try like this one bro**

```
jObject = new JSONObject(your response);
Iterator<String> keys = jo_jObject.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) {
String key = keys.next();
                String value = jo_jObject.getString(key);

                Log.v("**********", "**********");
                Log.v("category key", key);
                Log.v("category value", value);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, in combination with yanivtwin's answer I finally got it working.

Comment: Welcome, Enjoy bro... :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to cast wrongfully in this lines

```
 JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(forecastJsonString);
 return ja;
```

You know this is a Jsonobject by looking at the json , marked as{} , Jsonarray is marked as [], change it to JSONObject and the rest of the code accordingly , or change the response from the server (if you have access to it),
both solutions will work just fine.