# How to iterate through JSONObject

Tags: java, json, loops

How would I iterate trough this JSON string that is in a JSONObject?:

```
[
   {"Suggestion": "Roosendaal"},
   {"Suggestion": "Rucphen"},
   {"Suggestion": "Rijsbergen"},
   {"Suggestion": "Rijen"},
   {"Suggestion": "Raamsdonksveer"},
   {"Suggestion": "Raamsdonk"},
   {"Suggestion": "Rijswijk NB"}
]
```

Comment: This is `JSONArray`, you could iterate it as simple Array, Have a look at [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6376083/593709)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using org.json for that.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);
int length = array.length();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(o);
}
```

Where `s` is your `String`.