# JSON array as value getting text

Tags: php, android, json

I have created API for creating a customer in PHP, the client side is in `Android` would use a `POST` request to access this API. For testing I have used chrome postman where I had used post data as :

```
{"name":"test","marks":["12","13","16"],"age":19}
```

and it is working fine.

I am getting marks as array itself `["12","13","16"]`.

But from android client I am getting as text `["12","13","14"]`.

What may be the possible reason?

Comment: @PRASANTH Im not sure I have understood your doubt properly; but from your post, what I feel is that, you have confusion on the JSON data available in Android client, Im I right? You want to get the response in the form of a JSON object.

Comment: @rahul exactly no problem for web but there may be some problem with content type.

Comment: @PRASANTH you mean, you are not getting a proper json response in the Android side? If it works on the Postman, Im sure there is some trouble with the codes in the client side. Can you post that here?

Comment: @PRASANTH try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java

Answer (score 0):

POST it as :

```
{"name":"test","marks":[12,13,16],"age":19}
```

You are posting it as String inside array `["12","13","16"]`

Comment: not it was just an test data it can be  ["test","test","test"] both are not working for me.

Comment: Are you parseing it at server end?

Comment: yes iam just decoding it since the array is getting as string iam not able to decode.

Answer (score 0):

try to use it like

```
{"name":"test","marks":["12","13","16"],"age":19}
```

Comment: how you are using the json string, its working for me

Comment: How did u parse {"name":"test","marks":[{"12","13","16"}],"age":19}?

Comment: in php i would use simple json_encode for marks param which would be as that of web

Comment: For android i havnt put content type "application/json". Is that the reason.

Comment: you are using it without key so it should be like ["12","13","16"]

Comment: @HarishSingh Still it gives me string.