# How to iterate over this json array in java

Tags: java, json

```
["[{\"timeFrom\":\"06:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"09:00:00\",\"title\":\"First\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"09:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"12:00:00\",\"title\":\"Second\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"12:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"16:00:00\",\"title\":\"Third\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"16:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"20:00:00\",\"title\":\"Fourth\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"20:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"21:30:00\",\"title\":\"5th\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"21:30:00\",\"timeTo\":\"00:00:00\",\"title\":\"Dessert (within two hours of bedtime)th\"}]"]
```

I got this array when I log JSONArray. How can I iterate over it and get those values ?

**edit**

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyService.Meals.length(); ++i) { 
JSONObject rec = MyService.Meals.getJSONObject(i); String text = rec.getString("timeFrom"); 
}
```

Doesn't return anything because MyService.Meals.length() = 1.

MyService.Meals is JSONArray instance

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java)

Comment: Try the examples on this page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java

Comment: none of this examples worked, I have already tried it ...

Comment: Your JSON string looks malformed, the outer square brackets are surrounding one string, so of course the length of the array is one.

Comment: Remove the `["` and `"]` from the outside of the string, and then remove all the `\` in front of the quotes, and see what happens then

Comment: @Klazen108 it worked. Do you have idea why is json array malformed?

Comment: That would all depend on how your application is receiving the string

Comment: It is JSON parsed javascript array

Comment: Then I would wager there's an error in the JS code that's generating the string; one too many `[ ]`s around the JSON declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises because the format of your array is as follows:

```
[
  "[{\"timeFrom\":\"06:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"09:00:00\",\"title\":\"First\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"09:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"12:00:00\",\"title\":\"Second\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"12:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"16:00:00\",\"title\":\"Third\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"16:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"20:00:00\",\"title\":\"Fourth\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"20:00:00\",\"timeTo\":\"21:30:00\",\"title\":\"5th\"},{\"timeFrom\":\"21:30:00\",\"timeTo\":\"00:00:00\",\"title\":\"Dessert (within two hours of bedtime)th\"}]"
]
```

Which is an array of size one, with one string as its content.

You are expecting the array inside the string that has been string-encoded, which should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "timeFrom": "06: 00: 00",
    "timeTo": "09: 00: 00",
    "title": "First"
  },
  {
    "timeFrom": "09: 00: 00",
    "timeTo": "12: 00: 00",
    "title": "Second"
  },
  {
    "timeFrom": "12: 00: 00",
    "timeTo": "16: 00: 00",
    "title": "Third"
  },
  {
    "timeFrom": "16: 00: 00",
    "timeTo": "20: 00: 00",
    "title": "Fourth"
  },
  {
    "timeFrom": "20: 00: 00",
    "timeTo": "21: 30: 00",
    "title": "5th"
  },
  {
    "timeFrom": "21: 30: 00",
    "timeTo": "00: 00: 00",
    "title": "Dessert(withintwohoursofbedtime)th"
  }
]
```

Inspect the Javascript code, it seems like there is a section that is wrapping the array you want inside a string and putting that in another array. Inspect for an unnecessary call to `JSON.stringify()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the json object to a Java object, then you can read the data.

[See the JSON DOC](http://www.json.org/) for a list of functions you can use in Java.

Comment: I have already tried something like this: 

`for (int i = 0; i < MyService.Meals.length(); ++i) {
JSONObject rec = MyService.Meals.getJSONObject(i);
String text = rec.getString("timeFrom");
}`

but don't work and I am not sure why

Comment: And what was the result @DusanMalic ?

Comment: I tried to log it but it would't log, and than I saw that MyService.Meals.length() (that is json object) is 1, but I have no idea why...