# Fetch data of JSON array on Android

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I have a few test values in my database and i want to fetch them all in  android.
This is my following JSON output of the values inside my Database:

```
 [{"email_address":"some@email.com","comment":"qwehgashdgaskdaweq","date_comment":"2014-06-21","time_comment":"08:28:00","password":"somePass"},
 {"email_address":"some@email.com","comment":"asfasdasdasd","date_comment":"2104-06-12","time_comment":"09:03:00","password":"somePass"}
 {"email_address":"some@email.com","comment":"asdsfafd","date_comment":"2014-06-22","time_comment":"04:44:00","password":"somePass"}]
```

But every time that I run this code: http://prntscr.com/3vhs5j , it  only gives me the first line of the JSON output.: http://prntscr.com/3vi34b

How can I show all the rows( instead of 1 row)in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JSONObject provided by the android API. The JSONObject has a method called getJSONArray()

[http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray(java.lang.String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29)

your error there is that you are instantiating a JSONArray with your Object. you should try this:

`JSONArray myArray =jsonObject.getJSONArray();`

This is a snippet of code from one of my apps that worked very well to retrieve Json data.

```
 success = jObject.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
 vehicles = jObject.getJSONArray(Vehicle.TAG_VEHICLES);

        if(success == 1) {
            // loop through all the vehicles
            for(int i = 0; i < vehicles.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = vehicles.getJSONObject(i);

                // Get each element based on it's tag
                String year = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_YEAR);
                String model = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_MODEL);
                String brand = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_BRAND);
                String color = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_COLOR);
                String license_plate = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_LICENSE);
                String main_driver = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_DRIVER);
                String policeNumber = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_POLICENUMBER);
                String driversLicense = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_DRIVER_LICENSE);
                String licenseState = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_LICENSE_STATE);
                String driverBirthday = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_BIRTHDAY_MONTH) + "/" +
                        obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_BIRTHDAY_DAY) + "/" +
                        obj.get(Vehicle.TAG_BIRTHDAY_YEAR);
                String driverGender = obj.getString(Vehicle.TAG_DRIVER_GENDER);

                ListRowGroup group = new ListRowGroup(brand + " " + year + " " + model, brand);
                group.children.add(brand + " " + year + " " + model);
                group.children.add(policeNumber);
                group.children.add(model);
                group.children.add(color);
                group.children.add(license_plate);
                group.children.add(main_driver);
                group.children.add(driversLicense + "   -   " + licenseState);
                group.children.add(driverBirthday + "   -   " + driverGender);

                vehiclesGroup.append(i, group);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you put some of the code for getting the JSON in your question, to make it easier to reference, but, I don't see a loop, which is why it only gets the first line.

You may want to refer to this question: [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java) but basically use the `length` property of the JSONArray and loop through that many times.