# Parsing json array from the JSON object in Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am trying to parse a JSON array from a string which I receive from the server.

Example of the array is

```
{"data":[{"id":703,"status":0,"number":"123456","name":"Art"}]}
```

I am trying to parse that using the below code which is giving me Classcast Exception which shows JSonArray can not be cast to List

```
     JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result.toString());
     JSONArray slideContent = (JSONArray) o.get("data");
     Iterator i = ((List<NameValuePair>) slideContent).iterator();
     while (i.hasNext()) {
                     JSONObject slide = (JSONObject) i.next();
                     int title = (Integer)slide.get("id");
                     String Status = (String)slide.get("status");
                     String name = (String)slide.get("name");
                     String number = (String)slide.get("number");
                     Log.v("ONMESSAGE", title + " " + Status + " " + name + " " + number);
                    // System.out.println(title);
                 }
```

What should be the correct way of parsing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes sense as a `JSONArray` cannot be cast to a `List<>`, nor does it have an iterator.
JSONArray has a `length()` property which returns its length, and has several `get(int index)` methods which allow you to retrieve the element in that position.

So, considering all these, you may wish to write something like this:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result.toString());
JSONArray slideContent = o.getJSONArray("data");

for(int i = 0 ; i < slideContent.length() ; i++) {
    int title = slideContent.getInt("id");
    String Status = slideContent.getString("status");
    // Get your other values here
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the code to get the values from it?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not see the answer. Thanks for the answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this:

```
JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result.toString());  
JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");  
JSONObject jtemp ;  
ArrayList<MData/*a sample class to store data details*/> dataArray= new ArrayList<MData>();
MData mData;

    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
    {
        mData = new MData();
        jtemp = array.getJSONObject(i);  //get i record of your array
        //do some thing with this like  
        String id = jtemp.getString("id"); 
        mData.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
        ///and other details  
        dataArray.put(mData);  
   }
```

and MData.class

```
class MData{
  private int id;
  /....

 public void setId(int id){
     this.id = id;
 }
 //.....
}
```