# How could I create JSONArray/s from multiple arrays of JSON?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

In reference to [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java), when I have a single array

```
[{json object},{json object},{json object}]
```

I could easily create a JSONArray from the string as below.

```
int id;
String name;
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(string_of_json_array);
for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
    id = row.getInt("id");
    name = row.getString("name");
}
```

However, if I have JSON String of multiple array

```
[{json object},{json object},{json object}]
[{json object},{json object},{json object}]
[{json object},{json object},{json object}]
```

Can I still fit into a single JSONArray (i.e. making it JSONArray of JSONArray)? If not, how could I split them into multiple JSONArray (one for each of the row above)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("KEY");

 JSONArray arrayOfArrays = data.getJSONArray("KEY_2");

 int size = arrayOfArrays.length();

 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  yourObject = arrayOfArrays.getJSONArray(i).getString("Key_3");
}
```