# how to request an url with an edittext

Tags: java, android, json

i need to find a way to request an url with an edit text and display the json of that url. i have tried to use this code :

```
// URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String id = null;
    private static String url = "http://api.ccapp.it/v1/student/" + id + "/schedule/11";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_LESSON = "class";
    private static final String TAG_ROOM = "room";
    private static final String TAG_TEACHER = "teacher";

    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray contacts = null;

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.roosteralluz);

        //number input
        final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        //search button
        Button btnSearch =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.button34);
      btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               id = input.getText().toString();
               // Calling async task to get json
                new GetContacts().execute();
           }
        });
```

But when i try that code it returns this error: `org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head><title>Slim of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject` 
It is able to parse a link if i change id (look at code) to my own id. but i need to find a user his own id with an edittext.

Comment: Just add the code to your post, highlight it, then format it as code by doing `ctrl+k` so we can see it in the question.

Comment: someone who knows the awnser i need it realy soon

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java and this also may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java

Comment: thanks for the awnser but it didnt help

Comment: How did you read them so fast? Did you look at every aspect of the answers...because what the error says is that whatever String you are trying to convert can't be converted to a JSONObject. So I assume that you need to convert...

Comment: i work with a whole team so thats why i can try it so fast. but nothing helped

Comment: woops sorry didnt see your second link

Comment: im gonna try the other link

Comment: i've looked at the second link but its not what i meant

Comment: but still thanks for the awnser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using JsonArray, try Gson library to convert from Json to String and vice versa.