# Iterate through Parse JsonArray

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform, android-json

I'm retrieving a list of "read messages" that I store by objectID when clicking on a detail view. Now I'm attempting to retrieve these objectID's from the array like so:

```
JSONArray myArray = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getJSONArray("read_messages");
```

But how would I iterate through each string in that array for example Log each one in the console?

Comment: This question has been already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how would I iterate through each string in that array for example
>   Log each one in the console?

Use a loop then, E.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++) {
   Log.i("TEST", " " + myArray.optString(i)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length(); i++) {
    Log.d(TAG, myArray.getString(i));
}
```