# Iterating JSONArray Best practice

Tags: java, json, iterable

I am writing a service that uses a REST API of another service. I have ended up with a lot of methods that receive a JSON response that need to be parsed and passed into the system. I have been iterating n the following way

```
for (int i=0; i < JSONArray.length(); i ++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONArray.get(i);
}
```

Is this the only way and the recommended way of doing this? Since this does not implement an iterable interface?

I am using or.json.JSONArray

Comment: Could you imagine how many variations of such question (which style of iteration use) can be invented for various situations?

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java

Comment: What JSONArray are you talking about could be worth telling..

Comment: Yes none of them ( Including your comment) state what the best practice is.