# How can I loop over a json array in android?

Tags: java, php, android, json, gson

I have a string comming from php looking exactly like that : `"[{"id":"0","noteText":"Noteeeeeeee","date":"1232131","author":"John","authorId":"1"},{"id":"1","noteText":"Noteeeeeeee","date":"1232131","author":"Rob","authorId":"1"}]"`

Then in my `onCreate` in the `mainActiviry.java` I got to this point :

```
    String json = allNotes;
    //System.out.println("String to Json Array Stmt");
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement notes = parser.parse(allNotes);
    JsonArray notesArr = notes.getAsJsonArray();
```

My goal is to parse the json string to array of json objects, then loop over it and feed it to a `ListView`. The problem is that I cannot get there, since I am failing to loop over this `jsonArray`. My java knowledge is too limited, so other questions didn't help me much.

Can someone help, please?

p.s. i am using gson

Comment: I am using gson

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON Array iteration in Android/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3408985/json-array-iteration-in-android-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traverse the `JsonArray` using `size` while fetching the `JsonElement` using `get` function using `i` index and convert it into `JsonObject` using `getAsJsonObject()` function

```
    JsonParser parser  = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement notes  = parser.parse(s);
    JsonArray notesArr = notes.getAsJsonArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < notesArr.size(); i++) {
        // get your jsonobject 
        JsonObject obj = notesArr.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

       // do the same for the rest of the elements like date , author ,authorId
        String id,noteText,author;

        // fetch data from object
        id       = obj.get("id").getAsString();
        noteText = obj.get("noteText").getAsString();
        author   = obj.get("author").getAsString();

        // Store these values in list or objects you want

        System.out.println(id);
        System.out.println(noteText);
        System.out.println(author);
    }
```

output :

```
0
Noteeeeeeee
John
1
Noteeeeeeee
Rob
```